# Javascript create zip file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zip, admin-on-rest

I am developing a website using react.js and admin-on-rest. One feature is allowing users to upload a pdf file.

I get the file as type `FILE` and want to get the file from `FILE`, compress it to zip, and then make it to type `FILE`.

So it should be `FILE` -> origin file -> zip file -> `FILE` from zip file.

I tried JSZip but still can not figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Garrick following are the steps you need to take.

1) handle fileupload in a rest wrapper
https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#decorating-your-rest-client-example-of-file-upload

the above example is for image upload. But you will essentially be doing the same thing.

2)

```
const addUploadCapabilities = requestHandler => (type, resource, params) => {
    if (type === 'UPDATE' && resource === 'posts') {
       //use jszip to zip file here and package it however you need
       // call the API with zipped file
   } return requestHandler(type, resource, params);
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JSZIP](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples.html).

**use npm to install JSZIP

```
let zip = require('jszip')();
//hoping you have already taken input
let input = document.getElementById('fileInput'); // fileInput is id of my input element
let file = input.files[0];
let allZip =  zip.file(file.name, file);
console.log(allZip)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a small app called jszip for this. Try, it would help. https://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Thanks I have already tried jszip. But can jszip used in react.js?

Comment: Thanks so much. Will try it out